# What is causing null byte values in request to get filtered out?

Tags: php, curl, security

While trying to harden a PHP web app against [null byte poisoning](http://hakipedia.com/index.php/Poison_Null_Byte), I noticed that I was having a heck of a time actually sending a null byte in my request.

Using cURL, I was finally able to find a way to send null bytes in my requests, but I noticed something very odd:  No request parameters whose values include a null byte ever reach my PHP application.

As a proof of concept, I created a file named `test.php` on my server:

```
<?php echo json_encode($_GET), PHP_EOL;
```

Here's the result of some requests to this script:

```
> curl 'http://localhost/test.php?foo=bar&baz=nu%00ll'
{"foo":"bar"}

> curl 'http://localhost/test.php?foo=bar&b%00az=null'
{"foo":"bar","b":"null"}
```

It appears that keys are getting truncated at the null byte, and if the value contains a null byte, the parameter is removed from the request array entirely.

Using `print_r()` yields similar results:

```
<?php print_r($_GET);
```

```
> curl 'http://localhost/test.php?foo=bar&baz=nu%00ll'
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
)

> curl 'http://localhost/test.php?foo=bar&b%00az=null'
Array
(
    [foo] => bar
    [b] => null
)
```

Same thing happens if I modify my script and cURL requests to use `$_POST`.

Not that I'm complaining, but I do need to know why this is happening so that I can ensure that each webserver is configured correctly.

What is causing this behavior?

```
> php -v

PHP 5.3.3 (cli) (built: Jul  3 2012 16:40:30) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2010 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2010 Zend Technologies
    with Suhosin v0.9.29, Copyright (c) 2007, by SektionEins GmbH
```

Comment: You should probably use var_dump or print_r to display the get/post arrays to make sure it isn't json_encode that is causing the problem.

Comment: That's a fair point; I will note this in my question.

Comment: Disable Suhosin first. It might be taking care of that already.

Comment: Hakre pointed it out disabling Suhosin, yet you might wanna consider Suhosin is used for hardening in the first place, so just disable to test if Suhosin is already doing it for you.

Comment: @hakre You are correct.  I disabled Suhosin, and I was able to see the null byte in the incoming request.  Post an answer so I can award you the bounty (:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable Suhosin first. It takes care of that already.

As long as you have enabled it, you can not inject NUL bytes that easily.

Comment: This was it.  I disabled Suhosin, and the first curl request now returns `{"foo":"bar","baz":"nu\u0000ll"}`.  And now to turn Suhosin back on... but at least now I know what the cause was (:

Comment: @todofixthis: Thank you for the bounty and glad it helped you to clarify your issue.

Answer (score 3):

I point you to line 1010 of /main/SAPI.c of the PHP source code.

```
SAPI_API char *sapi_getenv(char *name, size_t name_len TSRMLS_DC)
{
    if (sapi_module.getenv) { 
        char *value, *tmp = sapi_module.getenv(name, name_len TSRMLS_CC);
        if (tmp) {
            value = estrdup(tmp);
        } else {
            return NULL;
        }
        if (sapi_module.input_filter) {
            sapi_module.input_filter(PARSE_ENV, name, &value, strlen(value), NULL TSRMLS_CC);
        }
        return value;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

estrdup() is #defined to _estrdup() which is on line 396 of /Zend/zend_alloc.c and makes use of both the standard library functions strlen() and memcpy() to do its bidding.  Basically estrdup() will only copy up to a null byte.

Comment: This is very useful, thank you, and it does illustrate very well why the key names get truncated when they contain null.  What I'm still unsure of, though, is why the key and value are skipped when the value contains a null.

Comment: That is strange. One would expect, at the very least, that `baz=nu` if not the full 5 character string.

Answer (score 0):

In many languages, a null byte symbolizes the end of a string. I'd send the data as hex and reinterpret it server side. I don't think GET supports binary.

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm understanding your answer correctly.  I don't want to modify my code to handle a specially-encoded null character; I want to simulate a null byte poisoning attack to make sure my code is protected against it.  Unless I am mistaken, this sort of attack is carried out by including a percent-encoded null (`%00`) in either the request URL or POST payload.

Answer (score 0):

**`var_dump($your_url);`** 

 If it contains UGLY/NULL characters, then try to **`TRIM()`** it at first.